# In JavaFX 2+ how can I retrieve the TreeView from a TreeItem?

Tags: treeview, javafx-2

I have an handler shared between several TreeViews.

In the handler I have access to a TreeItem instance, is there a (simple) way to determine the TreeView it belongs to?

Currently I'm relying on external variables to record the "currently active" TreeView, but that makes the code messy and, probably also rather brittle. Is there an alternative?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it is currently not possible, at least on JavaFX 2.2. Looking at TreeView source code (available [here](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/openjfx/2.2/master/rt/archive/tip.zip)), the `TreeView.setRoot(TreeItem<T> root)` method just sets the TreeView's root property, without setting some reference back to the TreeView on the root item. In this case, from the root element, there is no reference to the TreeView which it was inserted in.

Thus, even if it is possible to reach the root item from a deeper one using `TreeItem.getParent()`, it is not possible to reach the TreeView that has the item.